# Trying to send a specific audio file to a detail view in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer

I'm fairly new to iOS programming so pardon me if this is an easy issue to fix.

I'm building musical reference app that has a tableview that drills down to a detail.  Through the table, when you select a row it sends the detail a picture and text for a label and a scrollview.  I'm trying to make it so that I have a custom button on top of the picture and you will be able to tap that picture to play an audio example.

I've figured out how to get the button to play a sound but I can't figure out how to choose which audio file to play.

Here is the seque where I send the Arrays

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowBasicsDetails"]) {
    BasicsDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    detailViewController.basicsDetailModel = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                                              [self.basicsNames objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]],
                                              [self.basicsImages objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]],
                                              [self.basicsDetails objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]],
                                              [self.basicsAudios objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]],nil];
}
```

Here is the viewDidLoad from my detail view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.basicsLabel.text = [self.basicsDetailModel objectAtIndex:0];
self.basicsImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.basicsDetailModel objectAtIndex:1]];
self.basicsDetail.text = [self.basicsDetailModel objectAtIndex:2];
```

I'm planning on using AVAudioPlayer but all I can find on that pulls in a specific audio file like in this example from techotopia

```
[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
        pathForResource:@"Kalimba"
        ofType:@"mp3"]];
```

Comment: What I understood from your question is u are having a list of audio files as individual table rows and you want to play it by taking to next view right..  If I understood right are you having your audio file in your app directory index or inside your application??.